# What do these question marks next to heater resistance mean?

Tags: mems

[image]

This is from a sensor called MQ306A used for sensing gas.

My problem is that this same series of sensors from the MQ category have the same tin dioxide layer but they claim to sense various gases.

How is this possible?

Comment: Probably just a simple encoding error during conversion to PDF. If I had to guess, "3.8Ω ±0.5Ω"

Comment: Is it just me or is the question title completely unrelated to the actual text from the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get hold of a [better data sheet](https://gzhls.at/blob/ldb/f/d/9/f/79bb67ee01fd86e2b81166bd7f9b05804deb.pdf): -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is a sign of bad datasheet PDF conversion.

Either they are reminders to check actual data and update it, or symbols such as omega for ohm were missing from the used font, or a font was missing to render the PDF correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you’re viewing a copy of the [MQ306A Datasheet](http://www.kosmodrom.com.ua/data/gas/MQ306A.pdf) which is translated from a Chinese language. The question marks are likely the result of an encoding error. Inferring from context, I’d guess this is trying to say that the heater resistance is 3.8 Ohms, +/-0.5 Ohms.